# Why is my Linux machine forgetting it's DNS settings?

Tags: linux, dns

I am running a Kali Linux Virtual machine, it's based on Debian. I have entered my DNS settings in /etc/resolv.conf but when I reboot or resume the virtual machine the settings are forgotten which is very annoying, I am using a static IP address and I would like my DNS settings to stick. Is there a way to do this?

**If Config information**
[image: Ifconfig]

**/etc/resolv.conf**
[image]

Comment: Are you settings just deleted? Is there any comment when you open the file `/etc/resolv.conf` after a reboot?

Comment: Nothing at all I think it's just getting over ridden.

Comment: Are you using DHCP? If you are, then it is DHCP client overriding your `/etc/resolv.conf`. (Please, use proper formatting ie. not screenshots but instead just text for things like this.)

Comment: I have set a static IP address, can DHCP still be active and overriding these settings? My static IP isn't getting overwritten just the DNS servers.

Comment: Show the contents of /etc/network/interfaces (as text please, not a screendump).

Comment: dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4